# SVG appears small on mobile breakpoint

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG in a flex column with its items centred:

HTML: https://hatebin.com/ihmbhhnbci

CSS: https://hatebin.com/twdyzhjatn

It looks fine in a desktop view.

[image]

But in a mobile view it is tiny and has messed up padding.

[image]

I tried messing with the viewport, width, heights, and a surrounding container, but none of them fix the issue.

I would really appreciate some guidance as clearly I do not know what I am doing.

Comment: Did you tried using font-size? Do a test, use a inline-style on svg, like <svg style={{ fontSize: 24px }}, and you can try on the div that wrappes your svg too.

Comment: Try using a tight viewBox like `viewBox="222 16 152 116"` and set the width you want

Comment: @enxaneta setting a tighter view box does make it larger in mobile, but utterly huge in desktop.

Comment: then limit it...

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question, and not on another site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a width for the SVG. Also, replace the Bootstrap class `justify-content-center` with `align-items-center`.

```
svg {
  width: 40em;
}

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center p-5">
```

```css
svg {
    width: 40em;
}

.st2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: pink;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
    animation-name: draw;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes draw {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

.st3 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: pink;
    stroke-width: 0.35;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
    animation-name: draw;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.st4 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: pink;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 300;
    stroke-dashoffset: 300;
    animation-name: draw;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.st5 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.35;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 300;
    stroke-dashoffset: 300;
    animation-name: draw;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center p-5">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 150" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <path class="st2" d="M272.8,117.2c0,0-7.8-0.6-11.6-1.3c-3.9-0.7-7.9-3-12.7-5.8s-6.3-0.2-7.8-5.3c0,0-0.4-1.3-1.9-2.2c-1.5-0.9-3.3-1.8-3.8-5.4c-0.4-3.6-1.6-2-1-4.1"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M238.2,93.8c0,0-6.1,1.6-5.8-5.3"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M243.8,91.8c0,0-4.9,3.6-6.5-1c-1.6-4.6-5.4,1-5.3-4.9c0.1-5.9,0.6-8.1,2.2-10.3c0,0-3.4,1.6-2.8-4.6c0,0-5.6,0.6-1.5-6.1s2.8-1.4,3.5-7.5s5.3-9.7,5.9-9.9c0.7-0.2,2.5-3.3,5.2-0.9"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M253.4,76.1c0,0-2.7,2.1-5.3,0c-2.6-2.1-4.1,0.3-5.1,0.9c-1,0.6-10.5,1.5-7.3-4s1-5.8,4.6-8.6c0,0-0.1-3.8,4.5-8.8s5.1-6.1,7-6.1c1.9,0.1,2.3,1.3,2.3,1.3"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M251.8,49.6c0,0-1.1-0.8,3.1-4.7s5.5-6.3,9.8-5.9"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M269.2,40.8c0,0-1.7,2-3,0.8c-1.3-1.2-2.8-2.7,0-5.8c2.8-3.1,6.8-3.9,7.9-3.6c0,0,8.8-7.2,14.7-7c0,0,2.7-0.6,4.3,0"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M289.8,37.9c0,0-0.8-1.8,1.3-3.9s1.1-4.6,0.6-5.4c-0.5-0.8,0.4-4.3,3.9-4.7s2.9-0.9,4-1c1.1-0.1,4.9-1.5,10.4,0.5c0,0,7.2-1.1,8.6,0.6c0,0,6.6,3.8,6.3,9.6s-8.2,11.7-10.4,15.1s-1.1,4.3-0.9,5.2c0.2,0.9,1.4,8.8,0.3,11.6c-1.1,2.8-1.2,4-0.3,6.2c0.8,2.2-0.6,4-0.8,5.2c-0.2,1.2-1,5.1,1.7,4.9c2.6-0.1-0.9,4.2-2.2,5.3c-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.6-2.4,2.6"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M351.2,48.3c-4.1-3.5,0.6-7.4-5.8-8.7c-6.3-1.3-6.5-4.8-6.5-4.8c-7.1-18-20.8-11.2-20.8-11.2"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M335.8,28.9c0,0,2.2-0.5,3.7,1c0,0,4.5,0.1,5.4,2.2c0.9,2.1,4.4,3.4,5.4,3.1s5,3,5.8,7s3.7,4.5,4,9"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M359.5,48.6c0,0,6.5,4,7.6,10.6s3.3,7.4,4.1,8.7s1.9,2.2,1,7.5c-1,5.2,1.9,6,1.2,10.9c-0.7,4.9-2.4,2.9-3.3,5.1c-0.9,2.2-3,7.1-5.8,8.2c0,0-4.3,4.5-8.4,5.8c-4.1,1.3-7.4,2.8-10.3,5.5c-2.8,2.7-8.2,2.2-9.5,1.4c0,0-4.7,6.6-14.9,9s-12,3.7-12,3.7s-4.7,2.9-9.3-0.5l-0.6-0.4"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M327.8,79.7c-2.3-2-3.9,1.4-4,1.9c-0.1,0.5-4,4.7-5.1,5.8s-8.7,7.5-14,10.6c-5.3,3.2-16.8,8.3-16.8,8.3c-1.9-0.3-2.5,1.5-3.1,1.7c-0.7,0.2-2.2,0-2.1,7.1c0.2,7.1,4.2,5.1,5,6.2c0.8,1.1,3.1,1.7,4.2,1.8c1.2,0.2,4.2,3.5,9.2,0c5-3.5,7.3-3.1,7.3-3.1"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M245.4,103.3c0,0,5.5-2.2,9.9,3.2s6.8,4.3,9.1,4.2s2.2-0.6,3.9-0.6s3.5,1.6,5.3-1c0,0,3.2,3.7,6.7,1.1c3.5-2.6,1.3-5.8,5.4-9.5c4.1-3.7,5.4-0.1,8.6-2.7c0,0,0.8-0.9,1.2-1.8"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M249.3,103c0,0-2.1-1.3-2.6-4.4"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M283,117.5c-16.6,5.5-8.5-7.5-8.5-7.5"/>
            <g>
                <path class="st2" d="M344.9,86.4c-2.2,1-6.3,5.9-6.6,6.5c-0.3,0.6-8.1,9.9-11.6,8.8c-3.5-1.1-4.2,1.9-4.6,2.3s-2.3,3.3-5.6,5.2c-3.3,1.8-3.9,8.2-3.9,8.2"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M308.5,114.8c0,0,4.8-3.9,6.4-4.1"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st2" d="M327.8,50.6c0,0-0.4,3.1-2.3,4c-1.9,0.9-1.2,3.3,0,6.4c1.2,3-2.3,7.5-3.6,7.8c-1.3,0.3-2.2,4.7-1.9,6.9c0.3,2.2-1.3,2.8-1.3,2.8"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M323.3,50c0,0,1.8,2.6,1.7,4.9"/>
            </g>
            <path class="st3" d="M329.8,70.8c0,0,3-1,6-0.4c3,0.6,5.2,6.9,3.8,7.9c0,0-1.3,2.9-2.4,3.4"/>
            <g>
                <path class="st3" d="M351.3,81.1c0,0,0.9-3.9,3.1-4.7c2.1-0.8,0-7.8-3.8-8.3c-3.9-0.5-5.3-8.1-5.2-14.2s-6.3-11.4-10.4-8.2"/>
                <path class="st3" d="M358.1,80.4c0,0-1.1-2.7-3.7-4"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st2" d="M308.4,32.2c0,0,4.4,3.7-4,9.1c0,0-4.7,2-3.8,7.5s-3.7,5-5.2,8.8c-1.5,3.8,1.1,7.3,1.1,7.3"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M286.6,64.5c0,0,2.8-4.6,8.6-5.8"/>
            </g>
            <path class="st3" d="M285.4,40.1c0,0-2.6,2.4-2.9,5.5c-0.4,3.1-2.7,8.1-4.6,8.8c-1.9,0.7-8.5-1-9.7,0c-1.2,1-0.7,8.3-2.3,13c-1.6,4.7-5.7,6.2-8.3,2.6"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M279.8,74.4c0,0-3.6,0.9-3.7,3.2c-0.1,2.4-1.7,5-4.3,5.6c-2.6,0.6-3.1,2.5-4.4,3s-4.3,1.2-5.3,7.4c0,0-5.3,0-8.6-5.5s-8.7-4.2-8.9-3.6"/>
            <path class="st3" d="M274.6,99.2c0,0,1.2-10,10.2-11.5c9-1.5,6.9-5.9,8.1-7.2s5.6-4.7,8.9-4.3"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M314.8,123c0,0,7.5,13.1,21,7.1c0,0,6.9-1.7,7-5.4c0,0,10.8-1.7,8.2-17.4"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M235.8,99.6c0,0-6.2,1.4-8.6-5.7c-2.4-7-1.8-7.2-3.7-9.6s2-11.7,5-14.1"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M242.9,46c0,0,9.9-14.1,14.7-13.7"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M256.4,37.4c0,0,0.7-8,7.4-10.4s6.9-2.2,10.9-3.8s5-5.2,10.8-2.1"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M284.1,20.5c0,0,1.4-1.5,5.6-2.4c4.2-1,10.6-2.8,13.5,0c3,2.8,5.5,2.7,6.6,2.4c1.1-0.3,4.5,0,7.1,2.7"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <h1 class="fw-bolder text-center" style="font-size: 4.5rem; overflow-wrap: break-word;">BrainSociety</h1>
    <h2 class="fw-bold text-center" style="font-size: 0.9rem; color: pink">Neurology and Neurosurgery Society</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I make the brain bigger in desktop view?

Comment: You could declare `min-width` instead of `width` to allow the brain to be different sizes. You could also use either [container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container) or [media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) at-rules to declare a min-width and/or max-width at desired breakpoints. Just realize that the SVG has a 4-to-1 aspect ratio; it is four times wider than its height; the width of the visible brain is the same as the height (1/4th the width of the SVG.)